# Custom Order on DataTables Column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to supply a specific sort order for a DataTable text column, rather than just sorting ascending or descending alphabetical order.

For example, my goal would be to supply an "ascending" order like 
[Orange, Apple, Grape, Watermelon] where a column has only those values and when sort "descending" is selected, the order of the column will follow [Watermelon, Grape, Apple, Orange].

I haven't found a way to do this easily within DataTables yet and would appreciate any guidance!

**Update**
The enum plugin should be what I need - but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've added to my html:

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/enum.js"></script>
```

And I've added to my code:

```
$.fn.dataTable.enum( ['Orange','Apple','Grape','Watermelon'] );
$("#example").DataTable();
```

I've even tried explicitly defining the specific column in the table to be "enum":

```
    $("#example").DataTable({
      "columns": [
           {"type": "enum"}
      ]
    });
```

Is there anything I'm missing or haven't attempted yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the enum Plugin for this:
https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/enum
It will allow you to specify your order like this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.enum(['Orange', 'Apple', 'Grape', 'Watermelon']);
```

More Details in this Blogpost:
https://datatables.net/blog/2016-06-16

Comment: Thank you @Yush0 - this looks to be what I need, but I haven't been able to get it to work unfortunately. I updated the question with what I've tried to make it work.